# Shiny app that updates point shape on plot based on user input selection

Tags: r, plot, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am adding plot click functionality to a shiny app. As part of the app there is an input where the user can select an option.

I'd like that every time the user changes the input, the shape of the points on the plot changes. But only the new point changes. The points that are already on the plot should maintain their shape.

Below is my example. I tried resetting the input after every click but it didn't work, and I actually don't need to reset, just the shapes on the plot to respond to the input.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)



#UI
ui <- basicPage(
  
  tags$style(type="text/css", ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }"),
  
  uiOutput("input_event"),
  
  plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click", width = "350px", height="700px"))
  
  )

#server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #get click inputs
  val <- reactiveValues(clickx = NULL, clicky = NULL)
  
  #bind clicks
  observe({
    
    input$plot_click
    
    isolate({
      val$clickx = c(val$clickx, input$plot_click$x)
      val$clicky = c(val$clicky, input$plot_click$y)     
    })
  }) 
  
  
  #create event inputs
  output$input_event <- renderUI({
  
    radioGroupButtons(
    inputId = "event",
    label = "Select Event", 
    choices = c("Event1", "Event2", "Event3"),
    selected = "Shot Made",
    individual = TRUE,
    checkIcon = list(yes = tags$i(class = "fa fa-circle", style = "color: steelblue"),
                      no = tags$i(class = "fa fa-circle-o", style = "color: steelblue"))
    )
    
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    
    shinyjs::reset("event")
    
  })
  
  
  #interactive plot
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    shape <- if (input$event == "Event1") {19} else {18}
    
    # Set up a plot area with no plot
    plot(c(-25, 25), c(-50, 50), type = "n", axes = F , ylab = "", xlab = "")
    points(val$clickx, val$clicky, pch = shape)
    
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the shape together with the click x and y into the reactiveValue:

```r
  val <- reactiveValues(clickx = NULL, clicky = NULL, shape = NULL)
```

Then you insert it at each click.

```r
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
      req(input$event)
      val$clickx = c(val$clickx, input$plot_click$x)
      val$clicky = c(val$clicky, input$plot_click$y)
      val$shape = c(val$shape, if (input$event == "Event1") 19 else 18)
  })
```

I used observeEvent instead of observe and isolate, and require an event to be selected.

Finally, in the plot, use the saved shape:

```r
    points(val$clickx, val$clicky, pch = val$shape)
```